# Verify $\neg (Q \rightarrow (P \lor Q ) ) $ is a falsehood by deduction

Tags: propositional-calculus

This is the definition of $ \bf PL $

> Let $ S = S _ { \bf PL } $, the set of logical symbols for $ \bf PL $, be the union of the following three sets:
>
> $ Con = \{ \neg , \lor , \land , \rightarrow , \leftrightarrow \} $ is the set of connectives;
>
> $ Props = \{ P _ 1 , P _ 2 , P _ 3 , \dots \} $ is the (countably infinite) set of propositional variables; and
>
> $ \{ ( , ) \} $, the left and right parentheses.

And here are the [deduction rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Piwx.jpg).

[image]

I tried to start by assuming $ Q $.

Deduction verifying $ \neg ( Q \rightarrow ( P \lor Q ) ) $

1. $ Q ^ * \qquad \qquad \qquad $ Hypothetical
2. $ ( P \lor Q ) ^ * \qquad \qquad (VI) $ on $ ( 1 ) $
3. $ Q \rightarrow ( P \lor Q ) \qquad ( \rightarrow I ) $ on $ ( 1 , 2 ) $

But I can't find a falsehood. How can I continue?

I doubt I am already doing wrong in step 3. $ Q ^ * $ is already used for constructing $ ( P \lor Q ) ^ * $. If I want to construct $ Q \rightarrow ( P \lor Q ) $, I have to assume $ Q ^ { ** } $ before, isn't it?

Comment: I cannot understand what you meant after "I tried to start by assuming Q"

Comment: It seems to me that your deduction rules lack some weakening rules before all the axioms will be useful. And a cut rule or something similar that will allow a proof tree to branch and contain more than one axiom.

Comment: @Astyx Actually ¬(Q →(P ∨ Q)) is a conclusion. We are not given anything. So have to start by assuming something is true, like ((Q →(P ∨ Q)), or (P ∨ Q) or even ¬P. Here I assume Q to get start. I know it looks weird, but that's how the way it looks like that I learn from my class.

Comment: Do you know any equivalent of $Q \implies P$ ?

Comment: @Henning That's what all the rules I have so far :(

Comment: @Astyx No. Verify ¬(Q →(P ∨ Q)) is a falsehood. That's all the information I have.

Comment: yashirq Just curious: have you learned that from $A$ and $\lnot A$ you can derive $\bot$?  Are you familiar with the symbol $\bot$: contradiction (by definition, always false)?

Comment: @amWhy: That seems to be the $\neg E$ rule (except it has a subsequent explosion step built in, becasue the logical vocabulary here doesn't include $\bot$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step $(3)$ is fine. Having assumed $Q$, you derive $Q\lor P$ correctly in step (2). Then, you are justified by concluding (deriving) that $Q\rightarrow (P \lor Q)$ through $\to$ Introduction.

From $(3)\quad Q\to(P \lor Q))$ $\quad (\to I)\quad$ on $(1,2)\;\;$ [at which you've discharged the assumption Q]

you can use $\lnot\lnot\,$I  to conclude $$(4)\quad\lnot\lnot (Q\to (P\lor Q))\equiv \lnot (\lnot( Q\to (P\lor Q)))\qquad (\lnot\lnot I)\quad \text{ on } (3)$$

In other words, given your final comment about what you are seeking to do ("Verify ¬(Q →(P ∨ Q)) is a falsehood."),

you will have proven that it is **NOT** the case that $\lnot(Q\to(P\lor Q))$ is true. In other words, you will have proven that $\lnot(Q\to (P\lor Q))$ is indeed, false.

Comment: I thought ¬(Q→(P∨Q)) is a conclusion so we can't use it to compare with ¬¬(Q→(P∨Q)). But if we can use ¬(Q→(P∨Q)), why do we still have to do step 4? I think step 3 is enough. Q→(P∨Q) is already contradict with ¬(Q→(P∨Q))

Comment: Is it because of the parentheses?

Comment: One of the reasons I asked you in the comments below your question about deriving a contradiction ($\bot$), was whether, if you assumed (assumption) that $\lnot(Q \rightarrow (P\lor Q))\quad(4)$, after which you can use $\land$Introduction to write (in the subproof following the assumption, to write (5) $\;\big(Q\rightarrow(P \lor Q)\big) \land \lnot\big(Q\rightarrow (P\lor Q)\big)$.  The subsequent line in the subproof (step 6) would be $\bot$, after which you would need to conclude $\lnot\Big(\lnot(Q\rightarrow (P\lor Q))\Big)$

Comment: But the deduction rules you list do not seem to recognize $\bot$, $\lnot I$, nor $\lnot$E.  In any case, the four step proof I give you above is shorter, and follows only the deduction rules you listed in your question.

Comment: The solution is posted today. Basically, step 1,2,3 are fine. We can regard $¬(Q→(P∨Q))$ as a premise. So what we need to do is to add $¬(Q→(P∨Q))$ as step 1. Then we do step 5, (Q→(P∨Q))∧¬(Q→(P∨Q)). Done.